# How to fill in null values with previous values (Snowflake db)

Tags: datatable, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, difference

I have CTEs that result in a table similar to this:

| US_DATE_TIME | US_PRICE | NON_US_DATE_TIME | NON_US_PRICE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NULL | NULL | 2022-06-08 14:40:13.762 | NULL |
| 2022-03-03 15:02:05.963 | 11 | NULL | NULL |
| NULL | NULL | 2022-06-28 21:58:43.558 | 14 |
| 2022-03-03 15:42:08.203 | 41 | NULL | NULL |
| 2022-06-08 21:57:07.909 | 10 | 2022-03-03 15:00:21.814 | 14 |
| NULL | NULL | NULL | 38 |

I would like to show the changes in price for the two columns PRICE and NON_US_PRICE. For example, in the PRICE column, the price was originally NULL, then became 11 and stayed at 11 until in changed to 41, so the price would for row 3 for PRICE would be 11 instead of NULL and similarly, it would be 10 for the last row. I would like to apply this to the NON_US_PRICE column as well, where the price was NULL until it became 14, so the 4th and 5th row would also be 14 (instead of NULL) until it became 38. Is there a way I can do this? Would it be using something like `lag()`? In order to result in:

| US_DATE_TIME | US_PRICE | NON_US_DATE_TIME | NON_US_PRICE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NULL | NULL | 2022-06-08 14:40:13.762 | NULL |
| 2022-03-03 15:02:05.963 | 11 | NULL | NULL |
| NULL | 11 | 2022-06-28 21:58:43.558 | 14 |
| 2022-03-03 15:42:08.203 | 41 | NULL | 14 |
| 2022-06-08 21:57:07.909 | 10 | 2022-03-03 15:00:21.814 | 14 |
| NULL | 10 | NULL | 38 |

Comment: 1) Does this rule span the entire table or only within a group based on a key value (in other words, what would the window partition be)? 2) What is the order of the rows? Neither US_ID nor NON_US_ID are sorted.

Comment: I changed the data a little bit to remove the ID columns for a little more clarity. I don't have my data grouped in any particular way, but the rows are ordered by the date_time columns (both US_DATE_TIME and NON_US_DATE_TIME). So the prices tend to change when there is a new timestamp (but not always the case as you can see for row 5 where the non US price is still 14 event thought there is a new timestamp)

Comment: I thought maybe I could do something with the lag() /lead() functions and take the current row in the price column, check that it is null, and then if the previous row has a value, take that values as the value for the current row I am on (if there is a way to do that)

Comment: To confirm, the sort used for the table is `nvl(UD_DATE_TIME, NON_US_DATE_TIME) nulls last`, correct? Also, the partition spans the entire table, right?

Comment: I'm not familiar with how nvl() works but I'm not comparing US_DATE_TIME against NON_US_DATE_TIME, I am looking at each of those columns individually, and check the rows *within* them to compare them (For example, within US_PRICE, looking at the first row, seeing that it is NULL until it becomes 11, then the price will *stay* 11 until it changes to a new number) and apply the same procedure to NON_US_PRICE

Comment: I'm not sure that the partition spans the entire table (if I am understanding correctly) as US_DATE_TIME only refers to the other column that is US based (US_PRICE) and NON_US_DATE_TIME refers to the NON_US column (NON_US_PRICE)

Comment: Even through the explainations, I don't understand how this data is sorted. There is nothing in your sample data that suggests that current row 3 should be in the spot it's in. How would I submit an `ORDER BY` to get this particular sample data ordering?

Comment: If you're comparing the US and NON_US dates separately, then the rows are not sorted. The only sort is on whichever one is not null (the nvl function).

Comment: If we were to remove the NON_US_DATE_TIME and NON_US_PRICE columns so that we would just be looking at the first two columns, would this be achievable?

Comment: Removing those columns is not the main issue. What you can do to help others is the following:  1)  Edit your question to include a create table statement. 2) Follow that statement with an insert statement with a values clause to fill the table. 2) Specify a `select` statement that shows the exact order for the sorting. When you specify "previous values" the question becomes "previous to what?" There must be a sort order applied and with a number of null values in the date column it's unclear how to sort. That's why I asked if the sort would be the first non-null date using the nvl() function.

Answer (score 0):

So where Greg is trying to point out, is to "get the last value" you must have some details the sorts the data.

for your data, I have ignored asking you "how are you going to sort the data" and just adding those values, and you can work-out how to do this bit, thus, with this data:

```
WITH data(row_order, STOCK_id, US_DATE_TIME,    US_PRICE,   NON_US_DATE_TIME,   NON_US_PRICE) as (
    SELECT *
    FROM VALUES
    (1, 1, NULL,    NULL,   '2022-06-08 14:40:13.762',  NULL),
    (2, 1, '2022-03-03 15:02:05.963',   11, NULL,   NULL),
    (3, 1, NULL,    NULL,   '2022-06-28 21:58:43.558',  14),
    (4, 1, '2022-03-03 15:42:08.203',   41, NULL,   NULL),
    (5, 1, '2022-06-08 21:57:07.909',   10, '2022-03-03 15:00:21.814',  14),
    (6, 1, NULL,    NULL,   NULL,   38)
)
```

we can not do a per `stock_id` sorting by `row_order`, thus:

```
select  
    row_order
    ,US_DATE_TIME
    ,NVL(US_PRICE, LAG(US_PRICE) IGNORE NULLS OVER (partition by stock_id order by row_order)) as US_PRICE
    ,NON_US_DATE_TIME
    ,NVL(NON_US_PRICE, LAG(NON_US_PRICE) IGNORE NULLS OVER (partition by stock_id order by row_order)) as NON_US_PRICE
from data
order by row_order;
```

which gives:

| ROW_ORDER | US_DATE_TIME | US_PRICE | NON_US_DATE_TIME | NON_US_PRICE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | null | 2022-06-08 14:40:13.762 | null |
| 2 | 2022-03-03 15:02:05.963 | 11 | null | null |
| 3 | null | 11 | 2022-06-28 21:58:43.558 | 14 |
| 4 | 2022-03-03 15:42:08.203 | 41 | null | 14 |
| 5 | 2022-06-08 21:57:07.909 | 10 | 2022-03-03 15:00:21.814 | 14 |
| 6 | null | 10 | null | 38 |

this uses two function [NVL](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/nvl.html) (which is functionally the same as [COALESCE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/coalesce.html)) and [LAG](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/lag.html) with the IGNORE NULLS OVER clause